# Unit of work and common implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework

I have some questions regarding a common implementation of the UoW, Repository Pattern and EF:

```
public interface IAppUow
{
    void Commit();
    IRepository<Customer> Customer{ get; } // IRepository<T>
    IOrderRepository Order{ get; }         // implements IRepository<T>
}
```

My questions are:

1. If I need to add a new repository of whatever type, I have to change the UoW.  Is this a good practice? If not, is there a better way?
2. If I run `Commit() { context.SaveChanges(); }`, it will save the state of all the context's repositories. Is this a good way?

Answer (score 5):

This question is on the edge of being off-topic, there's really not much code to review here.

However your `IAppUow` interface has a number of flaws:

- **Naming**: I don't see a need for the `App` part. I think a better name would be more like `IUnitOfWork`.
- **Inconsistency**: You have `IRepository<Customer>`, and then `IOrderRepository` - why don't you have `IRepository<Order>` or `IOrderRepository`? When/if you *do* add repositories to your UoW interface, do you add a `IRepository<Entity>` or a `IEntityRepository`? This inconsistency makes it very hard to tell.

> If I need to add a new repository of whatever type, I have to change the UoW. Is this a good practice? If not, is there a better way?

An interface shouldn't be designed to change, as every change to an interface is a *breaking change*. I think you're mixing up the *abstraction* with its *implementation*; UoW encapsulates a *transaction* - and these things can be *committed* or *rolled back*. Thus, if I were to wrap the EF UoW into another layer of abstraction (I'll get back to that), I'd have a `void SaveChanges()` and `void DiscardChanges()` methods on the UoW interface.

> If I run `Commit() { context.SaveChanges(); }`, it will save the state of all the context's repositories. Is this a good way?

This is how Entity Framework works. `DbContext` *is* a unit of work; if you `Dispose()` the context before saving any changes, nothing gets to the database. If you `SaveChanges()`, the unit of work commits all changes made.

`DbContext` is an *implementation* of a unit of work - it exposes *repositories* (`IDbSet<TEntity>`) and a method to commit changes (and stuff about entity state management and model generation).

This might not be what you want to hear, but this answer sums up my thoughts pretty well: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/214022/68834 - in short, you don't need the pattern if you're using an Object/Relational Mapper.